# Can I put a personal private github repository on my resume?

Tags: resume

I created a prop-line generator for e-sports and I do not want it to be public/open sourced available for everyone to use. However, I would like to personally mention this project on my resume is there any issue with doing so despite individuals not being able to directly see it?

Comment: Self-host it.  If you don't know the URL you cannot see it.

Comment: You answered part of the question yourself. What is the point of sharing something people won't be able to see ?

Answer (score 7):

You **can** but it's probably better to instead talk about the project on your resume (rather than the repo) and the sort of technology you used to create it. A private repo is essentially no different than a personal project being stored on your local hard drive - if the code isn't going to be available for the potential employers to access then where it is has no relevance.

If you *do* intend to make the code available to them to see (but still keep it away from the public) you can put something like "code for this project is available on request" on your resume.